# How to remove previous data when executing AJAX request multiple times

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have an issue with ajax calling. It works correct except one thing, when I try to get data with the same option more than one times returns the new response but also still return the data of the previous response.

I think that there is something that I've missed.

**ajax script**

```
$('#search').on('click', function () {
    var date = $("#date").val();
    $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: '{{Route("dashboard.status")}}',
           
            data: {
                    date: date
                 },
           dataType: "JSon",
           success: function(response){
             console.log(response.manager_hourlog);
                // Employee  report script
              var colors = ["#1abc9c", "#2ecc71", "#3498db", "#9b59b6", "#34495e", "#16a085", "#27ae60", "#2980b9", "#8e44ad", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#e67e22", "#e74c3c", "#ecf0f1", "#95a5a6", "#f39c12", "#d35400", "#c0392b", "#bdc3c7", "#7f8c8d"];
                  @if ($auth->user_type != 1) 
                  // manager  report script
                  var managerchartbar = {
                    labels: response.manager_projects,
                    datasets: 
                [{ 
                  
                        label: response.users,
               backgroundColor: colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
                        data: response.totals    
                    },]
                };     
                    var ctx = document.getElementById('manager').getContext('2d');
                    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                      type: 'bar',
                      data: managerchartbar,
                      options: {
                        title: {
                          display: true,
                          text: 'Project Report chart'
                        },
                        tooltips: {
                          mode: 'index',
                          intersect: false
                        },
                        responsive: true,
                        scales: {
                          xAxes: [{
                            stacked: true,
                          }],
                          yAxes: [{
                            stacked: true
                          }]
                        }
                      }
                    });
                  @endif
              },
          error: function(xhr){
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
          }});
            });
          });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your method to POST for json request/response API, will be more secure and avoid laravel cache view it.

```
type: 'POST',
```

Try to change method to POST (do same for your api server and route).

If not work, please show your laravel API code.

Answer (score -1):

you should set `cache` property to false or append `"_={timestamp}"` to the GET parameter

so add cache to your request:

```
 cache:false
```

or append timestamp to your url:

```
url: '{{Route("dashboard.status")}}'+'_='+ + new Date().getTime(),
```

Comment: it's not receiving data in response when i used your code and i have also cache clear